# Has Batman ever ridden a bicycle?

Tags: dc, batman

The [Batcycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batcycle) is pretty common in canon, but it's always been a motorcycle. I can't find any references to Batman riding a completely unpowered bicycle (even in the campy Golden Age/Adam West era). Has it happened?

Comment: You haven't stated *which* Batman. I present to you, Batman Jones riding a bike - https://i.stack.imgur.com/N82rf.jpg

Comment: Yes, as played by Neil Innes.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fkyt3xi5_5k

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I give you [*Batman* #29](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_1_29) (June 1945), with Batman and Robin on penny-farthings:

[image: Robin (foreground left) and Batman (rear, right) are riding on penny-farthings; Robin is too short for his and can't reach the pedals, but is riding no-hands nonetheless. Batman is riding with his right hand and flashing an "ok" sign.]

Note that like the cover of [*World's Finest Comics* #54](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/World%27s_Finest_Vol_1_54) (props to RoamingShroob), the depicted scene seems to be a gag cover that *doesn't* appear in the issue itself.

[image: Robin labours to power a three-seat bicycle, while Batman (second) and Superman (third) sit with their arms and legs crossed enjoying the ride]

The title page for the story "[City without Guns](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_1_196#Synopsis_for_Batman:_%22City_Without_Guns%22)" (*Detective Comics* #196, 1953, reprinted in *Batman* #223, 1970) has an image of Batman and Robin riding penny-farthings on a London dock, but once again the image doesn't appear within the content of the story.

[image: Batman and Robin ride penny-farthings down a dock towards two crooks who are shooting at them]

I don't really understand the fascination with penny-farthings, but Batman rides a weird backwards one (with Robin in some kind of sidecar) in "[The Famous First Crimes](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/World%27s_Finest_Vol_1_25#Synopsis_for_Batman:_%22The_Famous_First_Crimes!%22)" (*World's Finest Comics* #25, November 1946); this one appears in several frames of the actual story:

[image: Page 66 from World's Finest Comics #25; in frame #4 Batman jumps from the seat of a sidecar into the saddle of a backwards penny-farthing (small wheel in front). In frame 5 Robin jumps from the sidecar onto an antique railway engine, and in frame 6 Batman follows him.]

I did find an unattributed image of Batman fighting crooks from a regular bicycle, but I don't remember this, and I haven't been able to track it down yet.

[image: Batman speeds towards the forward left on a white bicycle; with each hand he punches a criminal saying "Look-no hands!"]

But it does seem that yes, Batman has been depicted riding a bicycle.

(There is also a scene at the start of [*Batman: Black and White* #5](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman:_Black_and_White_Vol_2_5) (2021) where *Bruce Wayne* and Damian are riding mountain bikes to case out the site for a later operation, but I don't include that since it's not *Batman* riding the bicycle.)

Comment: Batman is also shown riding a tandem bicycle with both Robin and Superman on the cover of World's Finest Comics Vol. 1 No. 54.

Comment: Can't imagine Batman '66 could have made its entire TV run without ever putting him on a bicycle, but all attempts to google this are getting swamped by hits on the [Batcycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batcycle). People seem to really be enamored with that thing.

Comment: The backwards penny farthing is probably base don the [American Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Star_Bicycle) but the sidecar is probably an addition. High-wheel tricycles also existed (with 2 big wheels)

Comment: I don't think we need extended discussion on bike tricks here. If you want to have that discussion please take it to [chat] or another site where it would be more appropriate than here.

Answer (score 21):

### Yes

In the 1960s series, Batman hitches a ride on the back of the Alf-cycle (as Alfred pedals) in [The Catwoman Goeth](https://www.tor.com/2016/07/08/holy-rewatch-batman-the-sandman-cometh-the-catwoman-goeth/):

[image: "Stay tuned..." Alfred pedaling while Batman stands on the back]

See also this clip:

Bonus: Here is a behind-the-scenes photo of [Adam West](https://www.reddit.com/r/Moviesinthemaking/comments/2w8x4x/adam_west_rides_a_bike_yvonne_craig_gets_a_grip/) (in a Batman shirt) on a bicycle, next to Yvonne Craig. [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001842/mediaviewer/rm1925312000/) has several more in black and white.